# Reverting to slightly older version of Python2 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I currently have Python v2.7.13 installed on my Mac, but need to test out using v2.7.10, due to problem introduced in v2.7.11 for CQLSH.  How can I install this older version over the existing one?

Comment: you could give a try to virtualenv, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv

Comment: See also [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: pyenv did the trick!  thanks!  If you want to add an answer i'll accept.